# Streaming 1GB File in Python

Tags: python

How long should it take to stream a 1GB file in python on say a 2Ghz Intel Core 2 Duo machine?

```
fp = open('publisher_feed_8663.xml')
for line in fp:
   a = line.split('<')
```

I suppose I wasn't specific enough. This process takes 20+ minutes which is abnormally long. Based on empirical data, what is a reasonable time?

Comment: Need more specs. Hard drive speed is important. "How long should it take?" Use empirical data.

Comment: The question here is not "how long" but "how much memory, if at all possibile." -- Okay, 1GB is within the size limit for Python strings, so all operations should be possible. 10GB of data however are too many for a Python string to handle. Be very careful.

Comment: What is the file system where the file is stored?  That can make an enormous difference in the expected performance.  As a thought exercise consider the following options:  RAM disc, SCSI, SATA, PATA, external hdd on UBS2, external raid on USB2, thumb drive, external raid on 10Gb connection, and so on.

Comment: I suppose I wasn't specific enough. This process takes 20+ minutes which is abnormally long. Based on empirical data, what is a reasonable time?

Answer (score 8):

Your answer:

```
start = time.time()
fp = open('publisher_feed_8663.xml')
for line in fp:
   a = line.split('<')
print time.time() - start
```

You will require a 1GB file named `publisher_feed_8663.xml`, python and a 2Ghz Intel Core 2 Duo machine.

For parsing of XML, you probably want to use an event based stream parser, such as SAX or lxml. I recommend reading the lxml documentation about iterparse: http://lxml.de/parsing.html#iterparse-and-iterwalk

As for how long should this take, you can do trivial harddrive benchmarks on linux using tools like `hdparm -tT /dev/sda`.

More RAM always helps with processing large files, as the OS can keep a bigger disk cache.

Comment: I meant to ask how long should it take to process the file given those constraints. I am curious whether my hard-drives are significantly under performing.

Answer (score 3):

Other people have talked about the time, I'll talk about the processing (XML aside).

If you're doing something this massive, you should certainly look at generators. [This pdf](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/Generators.pdf) will teach you basically all you will ever need to know about generators. Any time you are either consuming or producing large amounts of data (especially serially) generators should be your very best friend.

Comment: This reference was very helpful.

Comment: Someone pointed it out to me about a year ago, and since then I've found all sorts of cases where a generator is *much* more appropriate. And it is the hands-down best reference for generators that I've ever seen, so I've taken to recommending it wherever I can. Personally I think generators are one of Python's most powerful and least-understood features.

Answer (score 1):

That will entirely depend on what's in the file. You're reading it a line at a time, which will mean a load of overhead calling the iterator again and again for the common case of lots of short lines. Use `fp.read(CHUNK)` with some large number for `CHUNK` to improve performance.

However, I'm not sure what you're doing with `split('<')`. You can't usefully process XML with tools as basic as that, or with line-at-a-time parsing, since XML is not line-based. If you actually want to do something with the XML infoset in the file as you read it, you should consider a SAX parser. (Then again, 1GB of XML? That's already non-sensible really.)

Comment: +1. `a = line.split("<")` for processing XML is troubling on several levels.